# How can I prove that $\int X(\omega )\,d\mathbb P(\omega )=\int x\,dF$ ? And what does $\mathbb P(\omega )$ mean?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $F(x)=\mathbb P\{X\leq x\}$ and $X:\Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ a random variable.

**Q1)** How can I prove that $$\int_\Omega  X(\omega)\,d\mathbb P(\omega ) = \int_{\mathbb R}x \, dF(x) \text{ ?}$$
I tried to make the substitution $x=X(\omega )$ but I can't compute $d\mathbb P$.

**Q2)** Moreover, I don't really understand the notation $\mathbb P(\omega )$ in $d\mathbb P(\omega )$. Indeed, $\mathbb P$ is a function that take element of $\mathcal P(\Omega )$ (i.e. measurable subset of $\Omega $), and in particular $\omega \in \Omega $, i.e. $\omega \notin \mathcal P(\Omega )$. So what mean $\mathbb P(\omega )$ ? Should it be $\mathbb P\{\omega \}$ ? But if yes, this is $0$ when $X$ it's continuous.

Answer (score 2):

The result itself is really just simple function approximation. No change of variable is required. The left side is a limit of simple function approximations. Each of those approximations corresponds exactly to a Riemann-Stieltjes approximation to the integral on the right side.

$d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$ is just notation: it tells you that the measure you are integrating with respect to is $\mathbb{P}$ and the variable of integration in the $\mathbb{P}$ integration is $\omega$. Sometimes people write the even more confusing $\mathbb{P}(d\omega)$ to mean the same thing.

Comment: I see better. But for Q1), let $X(\omega )=1_{B}(\omega )$ where $B$ is $\mathbb P-$measurable. Then $\int_\Omega  X(\omega )d\mathbb P=\mathbb P(B)$. Now how can I prove that $P(B)=\int xdF(x)$ ? Because I have $F(x)=\mathbb P\{X\leq x\}$ but I can't compute $\int xdF(x)$.

Comment: Moreover, if $X_n$ is a sequence of simple fonction s.t. $X_n\nearrow X$I will have $$\int X\mathbb d\mathbb P=\lim_{n\to \infty }\int X_n d\mathbb P\underset{(*)}{=}\lim_{n\to \infty }\int xdF(x)=\int xdF(x).$$ something looks wrong with $(*)$, because it doesn't depend on $n$...

Comment: @user380364 The RHS of (*) should involve the CDFs of $X_n$, call them $F_n$, not the CDF of $X$ itself. (This is what I mean when I say that the simple function approximations to $\int X_n d \mathbb{P}$ correspond exactly to Riemann-Stieltjes approximations to $\int x dF$, which are themselves exactly Riemann-Stieltjes integrals of the form $\int x dF_n$.

Comment: @Ian I think that the brackets in the notation $\mathbb{P}(dx)$ are dummies, i.e. you shouldn't think of $\mathbb{P}$ acting misteriously on $dx$, but instead as a "product" between $\mathbb{P}$ and $\operatorname{d}x$. So, probably, a less confusing notation would be $\mathbb{P}dx$. Actually, i think that the notation $\mathbb{P}(dx)$ is far less confusing that $d\mathbb{P}(x)$

Comment: The philosophical reason is that if we get a distributional primitive $F$ of $\mathbb{P}$ and it happens that $F$ is represented by a $C^1$ function, then $\mathbb{P}\in C^0$, and if $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_c$, $\langle\mathbb{P},\varphi\rangle$=$\langle F',\varphi\rangle=\int_\mathbb{R}\varphi(x)F'(x)dx=\int_\mathbb{R}\varphi(x)\mathbb{P}(x)dx$. Actually, such a formal "argument", shows that the notation $d\mathbb{P}(x)$ is less proper than $\mathbb{P}(dx)$: the first notation suggests that we are taking some differential of $\mathbb{P}$, while actually we are taking the differential of $F$.

Comment: Btw: I wrote $\mathbb{P}$ every time instead of $\mathbb{P}_X$, because I lacked characters... i hope that the fact i was using $dx$ instead of $d\omega$ should suggest that i was using the pushforward measure...